# Blazor module on Azure IOT-Edge

Tags: blazor, azure-iot-edge

We are developing modules for Azure IOT-Edge. As we need a simple HTML-GUI I decided to add a Blazor-module (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor) to our IOT-Edge solution.
But when I try to run my solution in the IOT-Edge-Simulator there are no stylesheets in my webpage.

When I run my Blazor-App with the IOT-Edge-Project from inside Visual Studio for Debugging it looks like this:
[image: Screenshot from]

When I start it as a dedicated project it looks like this:
[image]

When it is built and deployed via docker on my physical IOT-Edge devices it also works...

I first looked after the Content root path but it is the same in both scenarios...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: provide more details about the issue you are facing. Share screenshots if possible what is not working. Have a look at this [Attach Blazor to Azure IoT Edge](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2020/05/03/attach-blazor-to-azure-iot-edge-routing-showing-live-message-feed/) and see if it helps

Comment: I added the screenshots... Thx for the link but this site I know ;-)

Comment: From your description this looks like a blazor issue, not related with IoT Edge. Can you confirm if you suspect this is related with IoT Edge and if not remove the tag? Also would suggest you add more details. Are you using this project + blazor? https://github.com/Azure/iotedgehubdev